# in a C# windows forms property grid, can you provide descriptions for the categories themselves?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

In property grids, when you select an item it shows you the [description("")] helptext in the box at the bottom.

[image: property selected property grid]

When you are using the categorized view of the property grid, you also have the option to select the Category names themselves

[image: category selected property grid]

My Question is, is there a way to provide a description to the selected category that displays the same way description tags display for properties? E.g. when you select input you might see

```
Input
Items in this category are related to Input
```

Also, in case it's relevant, I'm just using a standard property grid populated by a class containing properties tagged with description and category

```
public class Foo
{
    [Category("Foo Category")]
    [Description("Foo Description help text")]
    public string fooProperty { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: I know that you are using the MS PropertyGrid, but just in case: The 3rd party component Smart PropertyGrid for WinForms allows you to set descriptions on categories. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property grid is "open source".

This description text is set by this https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/PropertyGridView.cs,4496

```
this.ownerGrid.SetStatusBox(gridEntry.PropertyLabel,gridEntry.PropertyDescription);
```

And `gridEntry` for a category is handled by the `CategoryGridEntry` class https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/CategoryGridEntry.cs which derives from `GridEntry` class which defines `PropertyDescription` property here https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/GridEntry.cs,909 by this:

```
  public virtual string PropertyDescription {
            get {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This property is not overridden in `CategoryGridEntry`, and all this is internal code, so, no, you can't have a description for categories grid entries.